# Updating and adding files in heroku repository

Tags: git, heroku

Im hosting my fb tab pages on heroku. Newbie in git command. I have modified my index.php, do I have to "git add" the file again to update my file in the repository? Also, how do I add bulk files. I have images, can I do bulk "git add" how. Thanks much. Tried google but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to commit all the files you have changed you can use

```
git add .
git commit -m "put your message here"
```

and then push to your heroku git repository.

I'd suggest you to pick up some basic facts about git, you can find an excellent guide here: http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1